# Android: How do I fix packaging error for Necessitas (Qt)?

Tags: android, qt, packaging

Anybody can help me with packaging error? 
In attempt of start of the program on the device I faced an error. Necessitas packet in case of execution of the command of clean debug gives out the following error:

> :-1: error: Packaging Error: Command 'C:\Users\iDom\necessitas/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant.bat clean debug' failed.Exit code: 2

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-qt/WdcIb1p38zg/ltJzXjzRg8EJ).. had the same issue(missing tools.jar)